# Cuda Device can't be applied despite: Installing latest pytorch on new environment of Anaconda, updating my 1070 Drivers, running on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, conda

I'm not going to say all the different things that I Have tried.

This should be the minimal thing to do and have a working GPU i think?

New Environemnt in anaconda.
New Drivers.
Installed Pytorch with anaconda with the aid of the official site

Still get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 # Device configuration
----> 2 import torch
      3 print(torch.cuda.is_available())
      4 print(device)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py:457
    443         raise ImportError(textwrap.dedent('''
    444             Failed to load PyTorch C extensions:
    445                 It appears that PyTorch has loaded the `torch/_C` folder
   (...)
    453                 or by running Python from a different directory.
    454             ''').strip()) from None
    455     raise  # If __file__ is not None the cause is unknown, so just re-raise.
--> 457 for name in dir(_C):
    458     if name[0] != '_' and not name.endswith('Base'):
    459         __all__.append(name)

NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

Comment: This does not look like a CUDA error, but an error in pytorch installation. It also does not look like this is run in a new env, as `~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10` is your base env. As a start, try without spyder/jupyter notebook and from your terminal, after activating your enw env in which you isntalled pytorch run `python` and in the python prompt do `import torch` to see if that works.

Comment: @FlyingTeller What the... In the anaconda terminal environment, it works..